# VideoView memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-videoview

Has any of you encountered a similar memory leak?
This is how I'm handling the VideoView at the moment

```
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(String.format("android.resource://%s/%s", getContext().getPackageName(), videoRes));
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mp -> {
        mp.setLooping(true);
        videoView.start();
    });
}
```

This is what I get on LeakCanary

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `ButterKnife.bind` returns `Unbinder` . Keep it as member and can `Unbinder.unbind` `onDetacheFromWindow` and check if you have the same leak

Comment: I'm using neither Butterknife nor a fragment - additionally, within `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` callback, there is a `mVideoView.stopPlayback()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ButterKnife with Fragments, you need to use the `Unbinder` in `onDestroyView()` to correctly dereference the Fragment's Views -- since Fragments have different life cycles to Activities.

There is a related issue [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/585).

Answer (score 3):

This fixed it for me within an `AppCompatActivity` that's not using Butterknife

**Step 1: Create a utility class**

```
public class AudioServiceContext extends ContextWrapper {

    public AudioServiceContext(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    public static ContextWrapper getContext(Context base) {
        return new AudioServiceContext(base);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSystemService(String name) {
        if (Context.AUDIO_SERVICE.equals(name)) {
            return getApplicationContext().getSystemService(name);
        }
        return super.getSystemService(name);
    }
}
```

**Step 2: within your Activity, use this utility class**

```
public class YourVideoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(AudioServiceContext.getContext(newBase));
    }

    //etc...
}
```

Credit: https://medium.com/@chauyan/confirmed-videoview-leak-on-android-ac502856a6cf

Comment: This is a correct answer. The explanation written here https://medium.com/@chauyan/confirmed-videoview-leak-on-android-ac502856a6cf

Answer (score 1):

Call `videoView.suspend()` in `onPause()` or `onDestory()`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/350567) by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Butterknife make sure to unbind, and if you aint't make sure to call videoView.stopPlayback() in your onDestroy

Comment: Calling `stopPlayback()` doesn't seem to be good enough. I get the same memory leak, even with that.