# VideoView leaks activity

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm showing video in an app using the following code in the `VideoActivity`:

```
binding.videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
binding.videoView.requestFocus();
binding.videoView.start();

binding.videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new 
    MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {      
           binding.progressBar.progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

binding.videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        binding.videoView.suspend();
        binding.videoView.stopPlayback();
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
});

binding.videoSkipButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    binding.videoView.suspend();
                    binding.videoView.stopPlayback();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

And after skipping / ending I get a report from leak canary that my activity:
[image]

How do I eliminate this leak?

I've also seen this question with similar leakcanary trace: [VideoView memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280440/videoview-memory-leak)

But there the problem was with `ButterKnife` unbinding. Do I need to do something similar with `DataBinding`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VideoView memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280440/videoview-memory-leak)

Comment: So have you found any solution?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? i faced the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add VideoView's pause(), resume() and stopPlayback() in your activity's onPause(), onResume() and onDestroy() methods:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    binding.videoView.resume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    binding.videoView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    binding.videoView.stopPlayback();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Hope it will help you.
Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it does not help :(

Comment: So sad :( @TpoM6oH