# VideoView Memory Leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-videoview

Encountered a VideoView Memory leak which already many have encountered. I have handled my code as below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + File.separator + R.raw.splash_video;
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    videoView.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(null);
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(null);
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

Memory Leak Report is shown below:

[image]

I tried the solution provided in the following links, but nothing worked.

https://gist.github.com/jankovd/891d96f476f7a9ce24e2

https://medium.com/@chauyan/confirmed-videoview-leak-on-android-ac502856a6cf

[VideoView memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280440/videoview-memory-leak)

Any help would be Appreciated!

Comment: Its a memory leak in the native VideoView (SDK). I recommend you to use SurfaceView and MediaPlayer together in order to achieve the VideoView kinda playback or you can switch to ExoPlayer.

Comment: @UmangBurman Thanks

Comment: Are you using `Butterknife`?

Comment: Are you using `Butterknife`? Well if you did: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280440/videoview-memory-leak?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @UmangBurman I have used ButterKnife and i have unbinded it as well as in the link you shared!

Comment: Okay, But still no luck?

Comment: @UmangBurman nothing worked!