# How to fix 'videoview memory leak issue'?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-videoview

I'm using VideoView to play some short videos, the code is very simple,but I always get the memory leak prompt.

I have googled  for days,some says it's videoview's bug, Google has fixed it in 2015, but I still can't fix it after trying some advice, for example: [VideoView memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280440/videoview-memory-leak), It doesn't work. All videos cound be played well, but always got the memory leak prompt.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera/3.mp4");
        videoView.setVideoPath(file.getPath());
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
```

The AVD I was using  is Android 7.0, I just tried 8.0, the leak was gone, so how to fix it under Android 7.0? Thanks.

Comment: can you post your log here so that we may know what exactly is the problem ?

Comment: As i assume, you are getting this issue while traveling over the fragments or activities. So you should trigger the GC by setting null the view object.